# Why "Did not wish to reply" appears before "African" in Alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

A bit odd one here: I am sorting these strings in JavaScript:

```
"African"
"French"
"Did not wish to reply"
"Spanish"
"Gujerati"
"Bengali"
```

To do so, I am using this chunk of code, where `nonPriorityLanguages` is the `var []` that contains the strings:

```
nonPriorityLanguages.sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return o1.description > o2.description;
});
```

For some unknown reason for me, the first one in the list is "Did not wish to reply". That doesn't respect the alphabetical order, because the result should be:

```
    "African"
    "Bengali"
    "Did not wish to reply"
    "French"
    "Gujerati"
    "Spanish"
```

Comment: please show your actual code.

Comment: Please read the question. The code that matters is there.

Comment: I don't see how you are building the array.

Comment: The code you have shouldn't produce the result you claim you're getting, here's an example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v5rt3ubw/**

Comment: Perhaps you have `" Did not wish to reply"` instead? Note the space.

Comment: What does your update have to do with the original question? Seems unrelated. Please don't change the question.

Comment: @stackpepe   You are now asking a completely different question. Please create a new question, instead of editing this one.

Comment: @FelixKling errr... everything?

Comment: I don't see how. The original question is "why is this ordered incorrectly" . The update is "how can I simplify this code".

Comment: @forgivenson What do you mean with "different"? I just wanted to extract the anonymous function that solves THIS question into a named one instead of having it twice.

Comment: @FelixKling This is not http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @stackpepe: Exactly. One more reason the update is inappropriate.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you're not getting the point; that's one more reason showing that you're wrong. This site is not for reviewing code, and the update is related with THIS question. In fact, it hasn't enough entity to be considered as a brand new one.

Comment: *"This site is not for reviewing code"* So, you think your update is not asking for code review? That surprises me. Either way, that's all beside the point. Yes, of course the update is related because it's about the same code. But the update is a about a different *problem* and you should avoid changing your question in such way.

Comment: Yes, of course I don't think it is. So, following your logic, Stack OverFlow is a site for code reviewing right? Then, knowing that http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for code reviewing as well, that's a duplicate isn't it? Look at that! You were trying to find why the question is wrong and you found that the site is wrong! Congrats!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `callback` in `sort` should be returning **less than, greater than or equal to zero** to determine which element is bigger. The problem you are seeing is because you are only returning 0 and 1 (`true` or `false`).

```
var myPersonnalSort = function (o1, o2) {
    if(o1.description > o2.description){
        return 1;
    }else if(o1.description < o2.description){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
};
nonPriorityLanguages.sort(myPersonnalSort);
priorityLanguages.sort(myPersonnalSort);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It's working fine mate! Can you please check the update?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any particular callback for this :

```
[
  "African",
  "French",
  "Spanish",
  "Did not wish to reply",
  "Gujerati",
  "Bengali"
].sort()
```

returns

```
[
  "African",
  "Bengali",
  "Did not wish to reply",
  "French",
  "Gujerati",
  "Spanish"
]
```

Comment: Hmmm... OP uses objects, not plain strings.